# Populate attribute in List of Objects in Java using Lambda

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I have a list of objects and I want to populate one attribute for each object in list.
I can do it using for loop like this.

```
for(Car car : cars) {
    String abcd = getSomeValue();
    car.setAbcd(abcd);
}
```

Can I do the same thing using Lambda in Java8.

Comment: Note: you are asking about a stream pipeline, not a lambda.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, not necessarily - see Eran answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use `forEach` :

```
cars.forEach(c -> c.setAbcd(getSomeValue()));
```